# Cleaning up this command

Tags: linux, grep, ps

I was wondering how I could reduce the amount of grep or pipes used in this command.

```
ps h -eo pid:1,uid,command | grep -v "screen" | grep java | grep -v "bash" | grep -v "grep"
```

Could it be reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this fit your needs ?

```
ps h -eo pid:1,uid,command | grep -Ev "screen|bash" | grep '[j]ava'
```

## explanations

- `[j]ava` is a known `regex` trick to avoid using `grep -v 'grep'`